# Can't see own VPN Server Windows

Tags: windows, vpn, sql, pptp

Found a similar issue here but involved Hyper-V VM's and Host.

In my case i sense something bizarre.

I've established a connection using only PPTP built-in windows connection between two points. Everything seems to be working, from the client i can access the router and other machines of the remote network just fine, problem is i can't access the very same computer that is providing me with the VPN tunnel connection.

Wait for it, i'll make it worse: i can't ping the windows machine where i've set the VPN server, can't access its own shared folder either, but when i open MSSQL Studio i can connect to its database! Basically i can't even ping the address 192.168.1.1 but when i try to connect from studio using 192.168.1.1\sqlinstance it connects no problem.

I appreciate any help you can provide, i don't know what i'm missing tbh...?

TLDR: windows -> windows PPTP, can access network all around but the very single windows pc that's providing me the access tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, did you try disabling the firewall on RRAS server?

Comment: port 1723 tcp, both in and out.

Comment: I meant disabling the firewall completely. It would show if it's a firewall issue or not.

Comment: Tested with barenaked firewall, still no progress...

Oh and i'll add one more into the pile, small detail i forgot to mention: the troublesome-pc-vpn-server is able to connect (files, ping, etc) just fine to the client pc using the VPN